# How to change order of string based on dates

Tags: stata

I received data with a string variable that looks something like:

```
var_name
25-DEC-99: A11, B14, C89; 28-FEB-94: A27, B94, C30
01-APR-11: A25, B82, C65
04-JUL-09: A21, B55, C26; 12-MAR-03: A11, B72, C68; 08-JUN-11: A62, B47, C82
12-JUN-00: A77, B19, C73; 03-JUL-12: A99, B04, C54
27-OCT-15: A22, B95, C08
```

And so on. My goal is to split these strings up into different variable names. The variable names would be `v1_date`, `v1_A`, `v1_B`, `v1_C`, `v2_date`, `v2_A`, `v2_B`, `v2_C`, `v3_date`, `v3_A`, `v3_B`, `v3_C`.

I can use `split var_name, p(";")`, rename to be `v1`, `v2`, and `v3`, and then `split` again to do this. But the problem is that I want `v1`, `v2`, and `v3` to be in chronological order based on the date and the data is not currently arranged in that fashion. How can I make it so that the date of `v1` comes before `v2` and the date of `v2` comes before the date of `v3`? For example in the first observation, I want `25-DEC-99: A11, B14, C89` to be associated with `v2` and `28-FEB-94: A27, B94, C30` to be associated with `v1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following gets you close, I believe. It uses both `split` and `reshape`.

```
clear
set more off

input ///
str100 myvar
"25-DEC-99: A11, B14, C89; 28-FEB-94: A27, B94, C30"
"01-APR-11: A25, B82, C65"
"04-JUL-09: A21, B55, C26; 12-MAR-03: A11, B72, C68; 08-JUN-11: A62, B47, C82"
"12-JUN-00: A77, B19, C73; 03-JUL-12: A99, B04, C54"
"27-OCT-15: A22, B95, C08"
end

split myvar, p(;)
drop myvar

gen obs = _n
reshape long myvar, i(obs)
drop if missing(myvar)

split myvar, p(:)
drop myvar

gen myvar11 = date(myvar1, "DMY", 2020)
format %td myvar11

drop myvar1
rename (myvar11 myvar2) (mydate mycells)
order mydate, before(mycells)

bysort obs (mydate) : gen neworder = _n
drop _j

reshape wide mydate mycells, i(obs) j(neworder)

list
```

You can loop over the `mycells` variables if you need to further `split` them.

Comment: This does what OP asked for, but my prediction is that the data structure will prove awkward.

Comment: @NickCox I agree. The original poster can keep a panel structure dropping the last `reshape`.

Answer (score 1):

In general, please consider using `dataex` (SSC) to create easy data examples.

You don't give all the (not trivial) code you used to `split` the variables. As it happens, I don't think your variable names are easy to work with, so I re-created the split in my own fashion. If you `reshape long` the split data, then sorting by date is easy, but I have pulled up short of the reverse `reshape wide`, as I suspect the long structure is much easier to work with.

```
clear
input str80 data
"25-DEC-99: A11, B14, C89; 28-FEB-94: A27, B94, C30"
"01-APR-11: A25, B82, C65"
"04-JUL-09: A21, B55, C26; 12-MAR-03: A11, B72, C68; 08-JUN-11: A62, B47, C82"
"12-JUN-00: A77, B19, C73; 03-JUL-12: A99, B04, C54"
"27-OCT-15: A22, B95, C08"
end 

split data, p(;) gen(x) 

local j = 1 
gen work = "" 
foreach x of var x* { 
    replace work = substr(`x', 1, strpos(`x', ":") - 1) 
    gen date`j' = daily(work, "DMY", 2050) 
    replace work = substr(`x', strpos(`x', ":") + 1, .) 
    split work, p(,) 
    rename (work1 work2 work3) (vA`j' vB`j' vC`j') 
    local ++j 
} 

drop work 
drop x* 
drop data 

gen id = _n 
edit 
reshape long date vA vB vC, i(id) j(which) 
drop if missing(date) 
bysort id (date): replace which = _n 
list, sepby(id) 

     +----------------------------------------+
     | id   which    date    vA     vB     vC |
     |----------------------------------------|
  1. |  1       1   12477   A27    B94    C30 |
  2. |  1       2   14603   A11    B14    C89 |
     |----------------------------------------|
  3. |  2       1   18718   A25    B82    C65 |
     |----------------------------------------|
  4. |  3       1   15776   A11    B72    C68 |
  5. |  3       2   18082   A21    B55    C26 |
  6. |  3       3   18786   A62    B47    C82 |
     |----------------------------------------|
  7. |  4       1   14773   A77    B19    C73 |
  8. |  4       2   19177   A99    B04    C54 |
     |----------------------------------------|
  9. |  5       1   20388   A22    B95    C08 |
     +----------------------------------------+
```